# How can I render html file in twisted resource in python?

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

Currently i am doing this

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource

class MyPostResource(Resource):
    def render_GET(self, request):
        html_file = open("form.html","rb")
        html_file = html_file.readlines()
        html_file = "\n".join(html_file)
        return html_file
```

what is the proper way to render a html file in twisted resource in python?

Comment: Can't you just `return open("form.html","rb").read()` here? What's the point of reading the lines if you will just join them back?

Comment: Also, what you are looking for is here http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/twisted-templates.html

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks man!